# Angular 6 router loses route params

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviour working with Angular 6's routing.
Given a main app, and lazy loaded module, I can access domain/base/name successfully, but all the recommended ways to access the route parameter are coming up null.

```
//  Main routing module
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: 'base', loadChildren: 'baseModule' },
    ]
  }
];

----
----

//  Lazy loaded router module
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: BaseComponent, children: [
      { path: ':name', component: ChildComponent }
    ]
  }
];

----
----

  //    Base Component
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.foo = params.get('name');
    console.log(this.foo);
  });
```

Given these blocks of code, this.foo *always* comes up as null.
Am I somehow misconfiguring, or misunderstanding this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route with parameter i.e `{ path: ':name', component: ChildComponent }`,
will open the child component, and therefore, the code to access the route parameter should be in the ChildComponent instead of BaseComponent.

Comment: I see, so I can only access a route parameter at the level the route is handled.
In the event that I need to handle some logic in the base component, is there a recommended way of getting the route param?

Comment: Yes. Do you need that parameter in child as well? Otherwise you can just add the parameter to base route.

Comment: Yes I need it in both, mostly in the child but for a few bits in the parent.

Comment: I don't think you can do that then. Instead, you can send the value to the parent component and store that value in a shared service, and then access it in the child component.